# Loop through object, then pass values to axios function, render results in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Just starting to learn react and need some pointers on how to loop through an object and pass the values into an axios get request, then store the data and render it on the screen.

I have an array of multiple objects like so:

```
const albums = [
  {
    artist: 'Artist 1',
    album: 'Album 1'
  },
  {
    artist: 'Artist 2',
    album: 'Album 2'
  },
  {
     artist: 'Artist 3',
    album: 'Album 3'
  }
];
```

I want to iterate though the albums and pass the values into an axios GET request for Last.fm API:

```
fetchAlbum(artist, title) {
  axios.get(`https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=API_KEY&artist=${artist}&album=${title}&format=json`)
  .then(res => {
    // ...
  })
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchAlbum('Artist 1','Album 1');
  this.fetchAlbum('Artist 2','Album 2');
  this.fetchAlbum('Artist 3','Album 3');
}
```

The response returns data (specifically album image URL) that I want to use to create a grid of albums, rendered as the component. Do I need to push all of this response data into the state and then loop through and render it from there? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to request multiple APIs concurrently, you can use axios.all function. Refer to [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for more details. I have included a basic pseudo code to illustrate how can we do what you ask for. Please refer to this example. If you want further clarification, you can ask.

You can check how setState works referring to [this post](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b).

```
/* Basic Example */
class App extends React.Component {
  albums = [];
  baseUrl = `https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=API_KEY`;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.albums = [{artist: "Artist 1",album: "Album 1"}, ..... ]
    this.state = {
      imageUrls: []
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    axios.all(this.albums.map(u => axios.get(`{this.baseUrl}&artist=${u.artist}&album=${u.album}&format=json`)))
      .then(axios.spread((...res) => {
        // all requests are now complete
        console.log(res);

        //note res[0] will include first response, res[1] will include second response
        //now you need to manipulate data as you required in state
        const imgUrls = this.manipulationFunc(res);
        this.setState(() => {
          return {imageUrls: imgUrls }
        })

      }));
  }

  manipulationFunc(data) {
    // process image url in each response and return it
    let imageUrls = []; 
    imageUrls = getImageUrlsFromDataUsingLoopOrMap; 
    return imageUrls ;
  }

  render() {
    const {imageUrls} = this.state
    const elem = imageUrls && imageUrls[0] ? 
    (imageUrls.map(url => (
     <img src={url} />
    )): null;
    return <div> {{elem}}  </div>;
  }
}
```

I haven't done it in actual editor. Apologies in case of syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you Niraj, I was able to get it to work! Only issue I ran into was that the setState will error if you do not set a variable for 'this' (otherwise use an arrow function on the axios spread). I also added in a shuffle array function to randomize the results :-)

Comment: @sternmd I have corrected my mistake! Good to know it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, but yes .. You would want to set those variables in the state of the component or fetch them prior to the component loading with `componentWillMount()` and then setting them in your state. Here is a

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { AlbumComponent } from "/components/album";

export class ParentContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      albums: [
        {
          artist: "Artist 1",
          album: "Album 1"
        },
        {
          artist: "Artist 2",
          album: "Album 2"
        },
        {
          artist: "Artist 3",
          album: "Album 3"
        }
      ],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.state.albums.forEach(album => this.fetchAlbum(album));
  }

  fetchAlbum = album => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=API_KEY&artist=${
          album.artist
        }&album=${album.title}&format=json`
      )
      .then(res => {
        let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state); // Duplicate your state so requests can be pushed in an array cleanly
        newState.albumMeta.push(res.data); // push the returned object to the array
        this.state.albums.length === newState.albums.length
          ? !newState.isLoading
          : newState.isLoading;
        this.setState(newState);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {!this.state.isLoading &&
          this.state.albumMeta.map(album => <AlbumComponent album={album}/>)}
        // Render your view out here based on if data is loaded
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: best method to fetch data is `componentDidMount` not `componentWillMount`, and `componentWillMount` is deprecated in react 16.3